# Issue logging into GitHub CLI to interact with GitHub from terminal

Tags: ruby, bash, terminal, zsh

Using terminal command "gh auth login -s 'user:email' -w"
and it keeps saying...
"-bash: gh: command not found".

When I closed and opened the terminal entering the same thing, it said...
"zsh: command not found: gh"

Sorry I'm a massive novice!

Checked syntax, restarted terminal, checked internet connection, messed around with double quotes, et! No luck

Comment: how did you install `gh`?  It is probably not in a location specified in your `PATH`.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path might help you

Comment: How did you verify that `gh` is in your PATH?